# how to perform calculations on vf page in EDIT mode?

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, formula-field

I have quantity and price fields to be entered by the end user on a vf page. Is it possible to show a formula field 'total amount' which will be quantity*price on the vf page in the edit mode itself?

Thanks!

Regards,
Manasi

Answer (score 3):

If it is a Visualforce page, you can use JavaScript/JQuery to do the calculations on client side and show the value on page.
Write JavaScript code to calculate the 'Total Amount' when the Quantity and Price fields' data is changed!

Answer (score 0):

use the code given below in your page it will peform the calculation on edit page. Make changes as per your need:

javascript code:

```
<script text="text/javascript">
 function updateOrder(){

  const TAXRATE = 0.925;
  const DONUTPRICE = 0.50;

  var numCakeDonuts = parseDonuts(document.getElementById("cakedonuts").value);
  var numGlazedDonuts = parseDonuts(document.getElementById("glazeddonuts").value);

  if(isNaN(numCakeDonuts))
   numCakeDonuts = 0;

  if(isNaN(numGlazedDonuts))
   numGlazedDonuts = 0;

  var subTotal = (numCakeDonuts + numGlazedDonuts) * DONUTPRICE;
  var tax = subTotal * TAXRATE;
  var total = subTotal + tax;

  document.getElementById("subTotal").value = "$" +subTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("tax").value = "$" +tax.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" +total.toFixed(2);
  }
</script>

<div id="frame">

      <form name="orderform" method="POST">


   <div class ="field>">
   # of cake donuts: <input type="text" id="cakedonuts" name="cakedonuts" value=""               onchange ="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>

      <div class ="field>">
   # of cake glazedonuts: <input type="text" id="glazeddonuts" name="glazeddonuts" value=""          onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>

       <div class ="field>">
   Pick-Up Minutes: <input type="" id="pickupMinutes" name="Pickup Minutes" value=""               onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>

         <div id="field">
   SubTotal: <input type="text" id="subTotal" name="subTotal" value=""               onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>

   <div id="field">
   Tax: <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value=""               onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>
   <div id="field">
   Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value=""               onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>


       <div class="field">
   <input type="button" value="Place Order" onclick="placeOrder(this.form);"/>
       </div>


      </form>

  </div>
```